# How to safely use android-logging-log4j when writing logs on external storage(SD-Card)?

Tags: java, android, logging, log4j, sd-card

As a long time log4j user, it is really enjoying to find log4j is available on Android with the help of this project https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/

For my current Android projects, I am writing logs both to logcat and a file on SD-Card, and the logging file is of great value to my project.

But some recent feedbacks from my beta testing users revealed that if the the SD-Card is removed while my application is writing logs, it will cause a Force-Close.

My current solution is to detect if external storage is mounted when log4j is first used; if no external storage is detected, I will disable log file output.

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;

import android.os.Environment;
import de.mindpipe.android.logging.log4j.LogConfigurator;

public class ConfigureLog4j {
    private static boolean configured = false;

    public static void configure() {
        if (configured == true) {
            return;
        }

        String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        final LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();

        if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);
            logConfigurator.setFileName(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "msgant.log");
        } else {
            logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(false);
        }
        logConfigurator.setRootLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        // Set log level of a specific logger
        logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
        logConfigurator.configure();

        configured = true;
    }
}
```

It is far from a perfect solution, and actually, it will not solve my current issue with log4j crash, because I can not decide when users try to unmount SD-Card.

Or I should make a wrapper around log4j, and implement the storage detection logic there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can always listen to the sdcard events and reconfigure log4j accordingly.

```
<receiver android:name="com.project.events.SdCardEventListener" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

this will allow you to reconfigure log4j when the card is removed (you can probably use the device internal storage till such a time a SD card is inserted again.

The `SdCardEventListener` should extend `BroadcastReceiver` and then reconfigure the logger as necessary.

Comment: thanks, I have following this lead right now, it seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

I would have log4j send logs to a [SocketAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html) listening on your server. The only issue with that is that `If the remote server is down, the logging requests are simply dropped`.

Comment: Thanks, for foreground usage only applications, this could be suitable, but my current application, which uses heavily background services, generating logs now and then, this is not desirable. Because if network is required all the time to gather meaningful logs, it will cause big issue on device's power usage.

Comment: the network is on most of the time on Android anyway, I don't see how this is an issue.

Comment: Hi, @hd1, the power usage difference between an idle network and an active one is quite different, you can try with the build-in power meter shipped with Android 4.0+. Anyway, thanks for your thought and definitely I will try it on my next app.